# Connecting to remote mysql server using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to connect to mysql server which is hosted on a remote server on DigitalOcean

```
const db = new Sequelize({
    host: x.x.x.x,
    port: 3306,
    database: bar,
    username: foo,
    password: buz,
    dialect: 'mysql'
})
```

But I get the following error

`Unhandled rejection SequelizeAccessDeniedError: Access denied for user 'foo'@'y.y.y.y' (using password: YES)`

Here, in the error it shows `y.y.y.y` (is my Public IP Address)

Why is it defaulting to my public IP? When I mentioned `x.x.x.x` in the config? Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Befòre you say, hey the duplicate is for php, not node.js - the rejection comes from mysql and the programming language is not relevant in this case.

Comment: Yes. As from the duplicate `You need to grant the permission to access the database from local` , I have solved the problem by granting access
`foo@'%'`